# New branch tracks local branch when created in Git

Tags: git

When I create a new branch in Git, it tracks the current local branch. This happens only on my computer:

```
sashoalm@HPC-SA222018 MINGW64 /c/Workspace/MyProject (master)
$ git checkout -b mybranch
Switched to a new branch 'mybranch'
Branch 'mybranch' set up to track local branch 'master'.
```

The problem is in the last line.
How can I stop this?

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I remembered I had made changes to my `.gitconfig`. Apparently this was the culprit:

```
[branch]
    autoSetupMerge = always
```

After removing it from my global `.gitconfig`, new branches stopped tracking the current local branch.